# How should I plot XYZ data points to create a depth image in RGB in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, open3d

I am working on a small project where I am given a 2D array of XYZ data. Something in this manner:

```
a = [[1,7,13,3,4],
     [6,21,32,11,2]]
```

where x represents the column of the array, y represents the row of the array, and z represents the content of the array, which is the distance. What I am trying to accomplish is to use the 2d array and plot a depth image in RGB. To elaborate, the closer the distance (z) value, I want the point to be plotted as red. And as the distance (z) values increase, I want to plot it yellow, green or blue depending on how large the distance is.

I added a sample picture for better clarification.
[image: Depth image]

I am trying to accomplish this in python. I tried researching into it, but most of the time I found how to extract XYZ data from a depth image or from a point cloud, instead of using XYZ data to plot a depth image.

Please let me know if this is possible or what python libraries are available to achieve this.

Thank you.

EDIT: I believe it might help noting that the 2D array consists of point cloud data generated by a rangefinder sensor. I want to be able to construct a still 2d image of the scanned area using the data points. I also want to make use of colormaps in order to allow me to visualize the depth of the image.

Comment: Do you know the distance of each image point and just look for [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/pcolormesh_levels.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-pcolormesh-levels-py) or do you have to calculate the distance based on your coordinates? Knowledge about [colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html?highlight=colormaps) will also come in handy.

Comment: A quite interesting tool is [`pptk`](https://heremaps.github.io/pptk/index.html) viewer. If you find it useful, I could help you with script example.

Comment: @Mr.T I do not know what the distance should between each point, but I am assuming it to be roughly around 1mm. And thanks for pointing me to the colormaps. Found it helpful.

Comment: @mathfux pptk looks promising. I appreciate your assistance. I am currently looking into it to see if I can figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: I vote against `pptk`. @Han is clearly a beginner and this problem  has an easy and standard solution in matplotlib using `imshow`. It's not the time to get wrapped up in an obscure `0.1.1` library with weak documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something along the lines of this?

```
from matplotlib.pylab import plt
a = [[1,7,13,3,4],
     [6,21,32,11,2]]
plt.matshow(a, cmap=plt.cm.viridis)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

You can pass large arrays such as images. Here I use an example image from matplotlib, I clip the colors to get a (120, 560) and not a (120, 560, 3) array and I display it:

```
from matplotlib.pylab import plt
from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data
fn = get_sample_data("logo2.png", asfileobj=False)
img = plt.imread(fn, format='png')[...,0] #get single color channel
plt.matshow(img,cmap=plt.cm.jet,interpolation='bicubic')#see imshow for more arguments
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

If I am not mistaken plt.matshow is a subclass of plt.imshow

Comment: @Mecgrad yes, you are right. However, the data I will be using might consist of more than 10000 data points, when constructed together, will give me an image. So I am not sure if this might be the way to go since the size of each pixel is big but the color mapping representation looks right to me. Thanks.

Comment: @Han the size of pixels is large because the array is composed of only a few values. I added a higher resolution example

Comment: @Quang Hoang I think matshow is a subclass of imshow. imshow may have different presets, otherwise it should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using `seaborn`:

Generating sample data:

```
pip install seaborn  # for those who have not yet installed seaborn
---
AND
---
import seaborn as sns

def func(x, y):
    return np.exp(-x**2-y**2)

xaxis = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
yaxis = np.linspace(-1, 1, 200)
result = func(xaxis[:,None], yaxis[None,:])
```

Plotting:

```
sns.heatmap(result, cmap=sns.color_palette("Spectral_r", as_cmap=True))
plt.yticks([],[])
plt.xticks([],[])
```

Result:
[image]